# email server have no reverse DNS entry

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, ndr

I'm having problem with one of my target email recipient, when I tried to send email to **abacus@abacusevents.com**, I got this error message from my email server:

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: mail.domain.com

abacus@abacusevents.com
mail.abacusevents.com #<mail.abacusevents.com #5.0.0 smtp; 554 "Refused. You have no reverse DNS entry. Contact abuse@suresupport.com for details."> #SMTP#
```

which PTR records should I add into my intenral DNS or my ISP DNS server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ISP needs to add the reverse PTR for your mail server. Just call them up and explain you need a "Reverse DNS Entry", they'll just need to know what your mail server's DNS name is (say mail.example.com) and they should be able to take care of it*.

Note: This assumes you have the mail server setup correctly otherwise and forward DNS working correctly as well (ex, mail.example.com globally resolves to 1.2.3.4).

Comment: ah so in this case the PTR records should be mail.mydomain.com to match up to the name used by my mail server ?