# Reverse DNS entry for sending secure email?

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2007, ndr

I'm having problem like the following when I tried to send to abacus@abacusevents.com:

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: mail.domain.com

abacus@abacusevents.com
mail.abacusevents.com [B]#<mail.abacusevents.com #5.0.0 smtp; 554 "Refused. You have no reverse DNS entry. Contact abuse@suresupport.com for details."> #SMTP#
```

which records should I add into my internal DNS or my ISP DNS server ? MX or PTR for this problem ?

and suppose i already got one service that is running on my one public static IP address:

eg: 25 SMTP and 80 normal website and 443 (OWA, HTTPS, etc...)

do i still need to add the reverse DNS for this server in the public facing DNS ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [email server have no reverse DNS entry](http://serverfault.com/questions/204575/email-server-have-no-reverse-dns-entry). If this is updated information for your earlier question, you should post it as an edit there.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a PTR record for the host, which used for sending mail.
Be sure, that you have valid SPF-record for your dns-zone and your host was included to it.

Comment: yes I do have SPF in place, but what to put into the PTR record ? my complete domain.com or the FQDN to my email server ? eg. mail.domain.com ?

Comment: In most cases, a PTR record presence (itself) only is important, because mail servers now refuse accept mail from hosts, which don't have any PTR records. Additionally they can check PTR record validity. Anyway, mail server's FQDN in PTR will be universal solution, and check that it is declared as MX for your zone and included to SPF record somehow, e.g. "mx" keyword is specified in SPF.